# Cambiar formato de fecha a GTM

Tags: php

Hola buenas tardes estoy obteniendo la fecha del servidor, pero ahora lo que no me quiere quedar es convertir esa fecha al siguiente formato “05:00:00.000 GMT Tue Aug 25 2020” el cual es formato GMT. Les comparto mi código de mi intento el cual está funcionando bien ya que únicamente lo que estoy sustituyendo es el día, mes y año, no sé si exista otra forma más fácil de convertir la fecha.

Mi intento

```
<?php
    $diaActual = date("D M j Y");  
    echo('05:00:00.000 GMT '.$diaActual);
?>
```

Comment: Ejecutando el codigo tal cual da el resultado que tu dices (`05:00:00.000 GMT Tue Aug 25 2020`). Deseas que todo este en la misma expresion en `date`?

Comment: si dese que siempre se manera el formato que comento, pero no se si exista una forma mas sencilla de hacerlo sin necesidad de concatenar la hora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes armar la cadena completa dentro de `date()` teniendo cuidado de escapando cada letra del texto literal (`GMT` a `\G\M\T`).

```
$diaActual = date("05:00:00.000 \G\M\T D M j Y");
echo($diaActual);
```